# Condition for a set to be min-homogeneous

Tags: combinatorics

Let X be a set of natural numbers, then a coloring $ c:[X]^n \longrightarrow \omega$ is regressive if $ c(X) \leq \min x $ for all $ x \in [X]^n$. A subset Y of X is called min-homoegeneous for a coloring c of $ [X]^n $ when for all $ x \in [X]^n $, $\min x = \min y$ implies $ c(x)=c(y) $.

Now let $ c:[X]^n \to \omega $ be a regressive coloration, then a subset H of X is min-homogeneous, if and only if every subset A of H of cardinality $ n+1 $ is min-homogeneus.

I'm looking for a proof of this statement, but I haven't found it. I have already one implication, which is very easy to see, but I'm stuck with proving H is homogeneous if every subset of H of cardinality A is min homegeneous.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably $n-1$ should be $n+1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The desired conclusion, that $H$ is min-homogeneous, means that $c(x)=c(y)$ whenever $x,y\in[H]^n$ have the same smallest element.  The given assumption says the same thing when $x\cup y$ has only $n+1$ elements, i.e., when $x$ and $y$ differ only in that a single element of $x$ has been removed and replaced by a different element to form $y$.  To get the desired conclusion from this hypothesis, consider any $x$ and $y$ as in the conclusion and try to join them by a sequence of "one-step" moves as in the hypothesis.  That is, we want a sequence
$
x=z_0, z_1, z_2, \dots, z_{k-1}, z_k=y
$
for some (finite) $k$ and some sets $z_i\in[H]^n$ such that each $z_i$ and $z_{i+1}$ differ by only a single element (and all the sets have the same minimum element).  That is, we want to get from $x$ to $y$ by changing one element at a time.  That's not hard to do; just consider each element of $x-y$ in turn and replace it with an element of $y-x$.